# Numpy remove a row from a multidimesional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a array like this

```
k = np.array([[   1. , -120.8,   39.5],
       [   0. , -120.5,   39.5],
       [   1. , -120.4,   39.5],
       [   1. , -120.3,   39.5]])
```

I am trying to remove the following row which is also at index 1 position.

```
b=np.array([   0. , -120.5,   39.5])
```

I have tried the traditional methods like the following:

```
k==b #try to get all True values at index 1 but instead got this
```

```
array([[False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]])
```

Other thing I tried:

```
k[~(k[:,0]==0.) & (k[:,1]==-120.5) & (k[:,1]==39.5)]
```

Got the result like this:

```
array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64)
```

I am really surprised why the above methods not working. By the way in the first method I am just trying to get the index so that i can use `np.delete` later. Also for this problem, I am assuming I don't know the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `k` and `b` are floats, so equality comparisons are subject to floating point inaccuracies. Use `np.isclose` instead:

```
k[~np.isclose(k, b).all(axis=1)]
# array([[   1. , -120.8,   39.5],
#        [   1. , -120.4,   39.5],
#        [   1. , -120.3,   39.5]])
```

Where

```
np.isclose(k, b).all(axis=1)
# array([False,  True, False, False])
```

Tells you which row of `k` matches `b`.